# Recreate Source Data from PivotTable Cache

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to extract the source data from a PivotTable that uses a PivotTable cache and place it into a blank spreadsheet. I tried the following but it returns an application-defined or object defined error.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Cells(1,1).CopyFromRecordset ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).Recordset
```

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivotcache.recordset%28office.11%29.aspx) indicates that PivotCache.Recordset is an ADO type, so this ought to work. I do have the ADO library enabled in references.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the value at runtime of `ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).Recordset`?

Comment: It's a recordset with recordcount = 49, but if I try to do the following I also get application-defined or object-defined error:

    Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Set objRecordset = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).Recordset

Comment: Put the ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).Recordset into watch window to see what exact type it is. That should help.

Comment: At runtime, the variable type is Integer/Variant. Of course objRecordset is type recordset. As soon as the app runs ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).Recordset shows Application-defined or Object-defined error in the watch window. Leads me to believe that maybe I am forgetting a reference. Perhaps something specific to PivotCache? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, there appears to be no way to directly manipulate PivotCache in Excel.

I did find a work around. The following code extracts the the pivot cache for every pivot table found in a workbook, puts it into a new pivot table and creates only one pivot field (to ensure that all rows from the pivot cache are incorporated in the total), and then fires ShowDetail, which creates a new sheet with all of the pivot table's data in.

I would still like to find a way to work directly with PivotCache but this gets the job done.

```
Public Sub ExtractPivotTableData()

    Dim objActiveBook As Workbook
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet
    Dim objPivotTable As PivotTable
    Dim objTempSheet As Worksheet
    Dim objTempPivot As PivotTable

    If TypeName(Application.Selection) <> "Range" Then
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) = 0 Then
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set objActiveBook = ActiveWorkbook
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    For Each objSheet In objActiveBook.Sheets
        For Each objPivotTable In objSheet.PivotTables
            With objActiveBook.Sheets.Add(, objSheet)
                With objPivotTable.PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(.Range("A1"))
                    .AddDataField .PivotFields(1)
                End With
                .Range("B2").ShowDetail = True
                objActiveBook.Sheets(.Index - 1).Name = "SOURCE DATA FOR SHEET " & objSheet.Index
                objActiveBook.Sheets(.Index - 1).Tab.Color = 255
                .Delete
            End With
        Next
    Next

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great workaround, thanks for posting it.  I just tried this in Excel 2010 and for whatever reason got an error on the .ShowDetail line.  However I could then manually do ShowDetails (through the UI context menu) on the one cell pivot table this code generated, and get a new sheet created that way.

Comment: Under Excel 2010 at least, the line: ".Range("B2").ShowDetail = True" should actually be: ".Range("A2").ShowDetail = True"  (A2 rather than B2)

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Immediate Window and type

?thisworkbook.PivotCaches(1).QueryType

If you get something other than 7 (xlADORecordset), then the Recordset property does not apply to this type of PivotCache and will return that error.

If you get an error on that line, then your PivotCache is not based on external data at all.

If your source data comes from ThisWorkbook (i.e. Excel data), then you can use

?thisworkbook.PivotCaches(1).SourceData

To create a range object and loop through it.

If your QueryType is 1 (xlODBCQuery), then SourceData will contain the connection string and commandtext for you to create and ADO recordset, like this:

```
Sub DumpODBCPivotCache()

    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1)
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open pc.SourceData(1)
    Set rs = cn.Execute(pc.SourceData(2))

    Sheet2.Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    cn.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

You need the ADO reference, but you said you already have that set.

Comment: Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).QueryType throws an error.

PivotCaches(1).SourceData returns the path to the external workbook on which the source data was stored. The pivot table was created using data from an external workbook (PivotTable(1).SaveData is True) which has since been deleted. I want to recreate the original source data from the pivot cache.

When you say "create a range object from SourceData and loop through it" I am guessing you mean use Range(SourceData) to reference the range object specified by SourceData, but that is not available to me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you double-click on a cell in a pivot table, or right-click and select "Show Detail" Excel exports the source data for that calculation onto a new spreadsheet in the same workbook. You can only do this one cell at a time, however. I need to do this for the entire pivot table and then automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself having the same problem, needing to scrape programmatically data coming different Excels with cached Pivot data.
Although the topic is a bit old, still looks there is no direct way to access the data.

Below you can find my code, which is a more generalized refinement of the already-posted solution.

The major difference is the **filter removal from fields**, as sometimes pivot comes with filters on, and if you call .Showdetail it will miss filtered data.

I use it to scrape from different file format without having to open them, it is serving me quite well thus far.

Hope it is useful.

Credit to spreadsheetguru.com on the filter cleaning routine (although I don't remember how much is original and how much is mine to be honest)

```
Option Explicit

        Sub ExtractPivotData(wbFullName As String, Optional wbSheetName As_
 String, Optional wbPivotName As String, Optional sOutputName As String, _
Optional sSheetOutputName As String)

    ' This routine extracts full data from an Excel workbook and saves it to an .xls file.

    Dim iPivotSheetCount As Integer

Dim wbPIVOT As Workbook, wbNEW As Workbook, wsPIVOT As Worksheet
Dim wsh As Worksheet, piv As PivotTable, pf As PivotField
Dim sSaveTo As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
calcOFF

Set wbPIVOT = Workbooks.Open(wbFullName)

    ' loop through sheets
    For Each wsh In wbPIVOT.Worksheets
        ' if it is the sheet we want, OR if no sheet specified (in which case loop through all)
        If (wsh.name = wbSheetName) Or (wbSheetName = "") Then
            For Each piv In wsh.PivotTables

            ' remove all filters and fields
            PivotFieldHandle piv, True, True

            ' make sure there's at least one (numeric) data field
            For Each pf In piv.PivotFields
                If pf.DataType = xlNumber Then
                    piv.AddDataField pf
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next pf

            ' make sure grand totals are in
            piv.ColumnGrand = True
            piv.RowGrand = True

            ' get da data
            piv.DataBodyRange.Cells(piv.DataBodyRange.Cells.count).ShowDetail = True

            ' rename data sheet
            If sSheetOutputName = "" Then sSheetOutputName = "datadump"
            wbPIVOT.Sheets(wsh.Index - 1).name = sSheetOutputName

            ' move it to new sheet
            Set wbNEW = Workbooks.Add
            wbPIVOT.Sheets(sSheetOutputName).Move Before:=wbNEW.Sheets(1)

            ' clean new file
            wbNEW.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
            wbNEW.Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
            wbNEW.Sheets("Sheet3").Delete

            ' save it
            If sOutputName = "" Then sOutputName = wbFullName
            sSaveTo = PathWithSlash(wbPIVOT.path) & FilenameNoExtension(sOutputName) & "_data_" & piv.name & ".xls"
            wbNEW.SaveAs sSaveTo
            wbNEW.Close
            Set wbNEW = Nothing

            Next piv
        End If
    Next wsh

wbPIVOT.Close False
Set wbPIVOT = Nothing

calcON
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub


Sub PivotFieldHandle(pTable As PivotTable, Optional filterClear As Boolean, Optional fieldRemove As Boolean, Optional field As String)
'PURPOSE: How to clear the Report Filter field
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim pf As PivotField

Select Case field

    Case ""
    ' no field specified - clear all!

        For Each pf In pTable.PivotFields
            Debug.Print pf.name
            If fieldRemove Then pf.Orientation = xlHidden
            If filterClear Then pf.ClearAllFilters
        Next pf


    Case Else
    'Option 1: Clear Out Any Previous Filtering
    Set pf = pTable.PivotFields(field)
    pf.ClearAllFilters

    '   Option 2: Show All (remove filtering)
    '   pf.CurrentPage = "(All)"
End Select

End Sub
```