# Is it possible to read an excel file with a pivot table into R?

Tags: r, import, pivot-table

First thing first: I have a couple of Pivot tables, for which I do not have access to the raw data. That is, I can change the pivot table in Excel, but that is all I can do.

I am hoping to find a way to read the raw data preferably using R. Does anyone know of anyway to import an Excel file with a pivot table or any other way to "solve" the problem?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I really have no idea where to start. I tried to read the file in R, but that produced a mistake. I tried to write an VBA code, but I was horrible at it, so that was of no help!

Comment: Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589948/how-to-take-data-from-pivottable-cache